# Make selenium wait untill all urls in the network request is printed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using `selenium-wire` and `requests` to print the network urls, status codes and some header attributes. I want selenium to wait untill all the urls are printed before moving on to next page.
 How do I add wait for same?
My code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import pytest
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


class Test_main():

    @pytest.fixture()
    def test_setup(self):
        # initiating browser
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:/Python/Sel_python/drivers/chromedriver v86/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)

        # terminate script
        yield
        self.driver.close()
        self.driver.quit()
        print("Test completed")

    
    def testcase_01(self, test_setup):
        self.driver.get("https://lifesciences.cactusglobal.com/")
        title = self.driver.title
        print("Page title: " + title)
        time.sleep(3)

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'here')]").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Allow all')]").click()
        time.sleep(5)

        for request in self.driver.requests:
            if request.response:
                print(
                    request.url,
                    request.response.status_code,
                    request.response.headers['Content-Type'],
                    request.response.headers['set-cookie']
                )
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'next')]").click()
```

I tried adding `time.sleep` but it halts the entire driver and when it resumes jumps to next url.
Is there any way to handle this using `webdriverwaits`?

Comment: Do you know the amount / count of requests expected to be there?

Comment: @Prophet: Nope. Its random count. Sometimes returns 14 urls, sometimes more than that.